# Videjs unable to play video on IE or Edge

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am using videjs plugin in order to play a video and it works fine on all browsers apart from........ you guessed it! Interner Explorer 11 and Edge! (what a shock lol).

I have spent hours trying to find a solution but cannot figure it out.  The file format is mp4 h.264 so that should be ok.

Not only does it not play the video but it will also not display the backup 'poster' value.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful to hear them.

Here is the HTML code I am using:

```
<header id="heroVideo">
  <div id="block2" style="width: 100%; height: 550px;" data-vide-bg="mp4: video/about-hero-vid-cut, poster: video/vid-img-mobile"
    data-vide-options="position: 0% 50%">
    <div id="videoHeroTitle">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h2 id="headTitle" class="display-2">Title</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```